# problems with ACLMessages in JADE

Tags: java, agents-jade

I have written a program and everything looks fine.. but at runtime agents confuse messages. for example I have this code:

```
ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessages (ACLMessage.INFORM);
msg.setContent = ("G" + groupID);
for(int i =0 ; i<50 ; i++){
    msg.addReceiver(new AID("MyClass" + i, AID.ISLOCALNAME));
}
send (msg);
```

and assume i receive it like this:

```
ACLMessage rcv = myAgent.receive();
```

and assume I define another ACLMessage in another part of the program for example named msg2.. in another block.. with content = "T" + temp.

when I receive the next message I realized that the messages are confused ... they are not received properly. I mean running the code below has 2 different results:

```
System.out.println("rcv Content is: " + rcv.getContent());
```

and the result will be: G1
and some times it is: T34

this mistaken messages make my program not to run correctly... I changed message formats like: "T" + groupID + "T" or other forms... but it didn't work..

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
After I learned to use message templates:

```
 case 17:{// in this case deligates send the avg to the supervisor
                if(!deligateFlag){
                    state++;
                    break;
                }

                ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
                msg.setConversationId("A");
                msg.setContent("V" + avg);
                //System.err.println("Content of rcv is: " + msg.getContent());
                msg.addReceiver(mySupervisor);
                send(msg);
                System.out.println(myAgent.getLocalName() 
                        + " Says: I am deligate of group " 
                        + group 
                        + " And I sent the average temp of my followers "
                        + "to the supervisor which is: " 
                        + mySupervisor.getLocalName());
                state++;
                break;
            }
            case 18:{/* in this case supervisor receives the avg temp of 
                each group and calculates the avg of averages and then 
                decides what to do*/
                if(!supervisorFlag){
                    n=1;
                    state++;
                    break;
                }
                //System.err.println("This is Beginning of case 18");
                if(supervisorFlag){
                    MessageTemplate mt = MessageTemplate.MatchConversationId("A");
                    ACLMessage msg = myAgent.receive(mt);
                    if (msg != null) { System.err.println("TContent is: " + msg.getContent());
                        dAvg += Character.getNumericValue(msg.getContent().charAt(1));

                        if(msg.getContent().charAt(0) == 'V'){
                            n++;
                            System.err.println("N is: " + n);
                        }
                    }
                    if(n > 4){

                                dAvg /= 4;
                                totalAvg = dAvg;
                                System.out.println("Supervisor " 
                                        + myAgent.getLocalName() 
                                        + "Says: The total average of whole system is: " 
                                        + totalAvg);
                        }
                        state++;
                        break;
```

The problem is, in the best case program runs until `if (n>4)` .. and everything stops .. no errors, no warnings .. it just stops.. even n goes to 5 but nothing happens ... I do not know what could be the exact problem.. whether ACL messages or I don't know ... generally I don't know why in 90% program doesn't print TContent . what will happen to the messages..

Comment: honestly i dont undestand what's wrong. dont you like messages order? Or you want to receive only messages with content ("G" + groupID)?

Comment: I am sorry for my poor explanation. the problem is that I want to receive only messages with a specific content. and when ever I write this if after each of them the program does not go to if statement. for example:


`ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessages (ACLMessage.INFORM);
msg.setContent = ("G" + groupID);
for(int i =0 ; i<50 ; i++){
    msg.addReceiver(new AID("MyClass" + i, AID.ISLOCALNAME));
}
send (msg);


ACLMessage rcv = myAgent.receive();

if(rcv.getContent().equals("G" + groupID) {
//do sth
}`

unfortunately the do sth part is never done and leaves me with problems...

Comment: how about receive(MessageTemplate pattern)?

Comment: I didn't find function like that you said in https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer4.html

How is that?..

Comment: posted answer and you can see this method in javadoc http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/core/Agent.html

Comment: Thanks, I know it could be strange, but although I found the functions but I do really need some examples, I tried but couldn't work with msg templates.. could you mind please explain some more, or show me examples if there is any on internet?....

Comment: What exactly dont work? agent1 sends message but agent2 dont receives it? if your project isnt commercial, can you attach more your code?

Comment: I post it as an edit to the question I asked .. and Thank you

Comment: why dont you use `block();` for waiting messages? Are you sure that `case 18` is executing after deligateAgent sent message?

Comment: @nikelyn Hello again, I wrote a block(); at the end of case 17, every time I debug the project, although state becomes 18, when case 17 is over, program doesn't enter case 18 and just hangs.. with no error massage ...
this happens when I put the line breakpoint at the end of a state and debug..
some times although state is still 18, it enters state 19 ..

my project is becoming a disaster -_-

Comment: the code that you attached both deligate agent and supervisor agent use? is it common code?

Comment: I have been working on it these days and I could solve it finally, but again I face the problem about working with acl messages, I'll write a comment for the answer you posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive specific aclMessages you can use myAgent.receive(MessageTemplate t).

For example, you want to send message

Agent1:

```
ACLMessage request = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
...     
request.setConversationId("G");
myAgent.send(request)
```

And you want your Agent2 to receive only messages with ConversationId = "G"

Agent2:

```
MessageTemplate mt = MessageTemplate.MatchConversationId("G");;
ACLMessage msg = myAgent.receive(mt);
if (msg != null) {
  // Process it
  ...
} else {
   block();
}
```

Comment: these solution worked for several cases, but in one case i wonder why it is not working and the condition `if (msg != null)` is always wrong which means the agent doesn't receive that message with that exact conversation ID.. what could be the possible reason?

Comment: i have the same issue, did you manage to solve this and, if yes, do  you remember how? Thank you.